# Refined Gerschgorin circle theorem: algebraic or geometric multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a square matrix $A$ with (i,j)th entry $a_{ij}$, we define Gerschgorin discs
$$
G_i \equiv \{z\in \mathbb{C}: \left|z-a_{ii}\right| \leq r_i\},\quad \text{where}\quad r_i \equiv \sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|.
$$
I'm familiar with the following statement of the Gerschgorin circle theorem:

> Thm. Given a square matrix $A$, all the eigenvalues of $A$ lie within the union of Gerschgorin discs of $A$. Moreover the number of eigenvalues in each connected component (counted with multiplicity) formed by the discs is equal to the number of discs that constitute that component.

My question is: is the number of eigenvalues in each connected component counted with *algebraic* multiplicity (# occurrences as a root of characteristic polynomial), or *geometric* (dimension of eigenspace)? The proof that I'm familiar with examines the eigenvalues of $A$ as one zeros-out off-diagonal entries (e.g. see the proof of Corollary 1 on [page 8 of this document](http://math.stmarys-ca.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/David-Marquis.pdf)). Based on this, it seems to me that the eigenvalues should be counted with algebraic multiplicity. Is this correct? If not, could someone sketch out why its geometric multiplicity instead?

Comment: Assume it is the geometric multiplicity-- then by counting, this implies all matrices are diagonalizable which can't be true....

Comment: It is algebraic multiplicity. The number of eigenvalues (counting geometric multiplicity) within an open domain in complex plane isn't a continuous function in terms of its entries. In contrast, the number of eigenvalues (counting algebraic multiplicity) is. The refined 
Gerschgorin Circle Theorem can be proved using a continuity argument.

Comment: achillehui Thank you--that's a super clear way to connect to the proof. @user8675309, I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, would you be willing to elaborate?